# can I inject data directly into session storage from server side selected data?

Tags: php, mysql, html, session-storage

I'm wondering if it is possible to do a server side select on a mysql database and inject the result directly into HTML5 session storage without using ajax. The scenario is as follows:

Assume that OK on the server side script, thus:

```
    header( "Content-type: application/json" );

    $jsondata = array();

    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($params))
    {
    $jsondata[]= array('field1'=>$Row["field1"], 
                           'field2'=>$Row["field2"],
                           'field3'=>$Row["field3"],
                           'field4'=>$Row["field4"]);
    };

    echo json_encode(array("eeData" => $jsondata));
```

Normally, if this was ajax I'd wait for the response and I could parse the result and deal with it that way. But that method is initiated on the client side, and is in effect a second  request to the server.

But, I was wondering if this could be achieved in the absolute initial request for the page ie on the very first request, getting the data and somehow injecting it directly into the session storage at the same time as the page is first served.

Please make comments if the principle is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how is the webserver supposed to reach into the browser to store this data? Until the websockets api becomes more widespread, the ONLY way for a server to send data to a client is when the client initiates the request. You cannot just 'reach out' to a browser and stuff data into it.

If you want this during the initial page request, you can always embed the data into the page that's being sent

```
<script>
    var data_to_store = <?php echo json_encode($your_structure) ?>;
</script>
```

It'd make for a 'fat' page, but it'd send the data in the same request. Any other method would require a second connection back to the server.

Comment: I agree with everything you said here, except that my knowledge doesn't extend as far as people like yourself. That's why I asked the question in case there was something I didn't know about yet.

Comment: see my comment above. This answer causes the entire served page to be written to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but if you want to insert something into LocalStorage when the page first loads, just load it into a Javascript variable then insert it. For example:

```
...

var dataToInsert = JSON.parse("<?php echo(json_encode(arra("eeData" => $jsondata))?>");
```

Then just work with `dataToInsert` like any other JS variable.

Comment: I tried both your and @Marc B and both broke the PHP execution in that the echo statement appears to cause the entire served HTML to be written to the screen. I know there is a small typographic error in your answer, and that the parsed JSON is an object not a variable, but that still didn't fix the issue. Oddly the JSON was correctly echoed so I know the PHP script is working.